# How can I use sticky positioning whilst using Smooth Scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

Hi I'm currently working on a horizontal scrolling site. I am very much a noob when it comes to javascript but I found a codepen that I modified to suit my needs.

I would like the button element to position sticky within the div but I think due to the javascript in use sticky positioning does not work. I have had a look at the documentation and can't seem to see anything that would work, however, I am very much a novice when it comes to javascript.

`button{ position: sticky; }`

Would anyone be able to give me a few pointers?

[Here is the codepen that I am working on](https://codepen.io/rahuldesign_/pen/jOBEGaO)

[Based on this original codepen](https://codepen.io/olig/pen/VwjYZLw)

[The js it is using](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/tree/b04c2e81444c3b6d90eafa504eb35994a9d47efb/docs)

I very much appreciate any help I can get thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how it supposed to work, but in my browser the message stays inside black section until right side of black section pushes it behind the screen.